# AVD is not valid. Configuration has changed since AVD creation in Intellij IDEA 13

Tags: android, intellij-idea, intellij-eap

This error appears when I updated IDEA CE to 132.1045 version.
AVD manager has no problem with this AVD.
I tried to recreate AVD from scratch but no result, same problem.
In SDK manager no updates.

[image: screenshot]

If click on "Continue Anyway" app deploys normal.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems like old API (for example 2.3.3) versions make this happen. I don't get error for api 17+ emulators.

Comment: API17, still doesn't work.

Comment: This is an annoying bug. Copying the device definition helps as coderazzi found out. But my virtual devices crashes after startup: "Unfortunately, System UI has stopped."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This problem happens to me after SDK updates when I am using any device based directly on the default Device definitions.

Furthermore: any new virtual device created with the default device definitions (Nexus 7, Nexus S, etc) gives directly the same error.

My solution is to duplicate these definitions:

1. In Android Virtual Device Manager / Device definitions -> select the definition to use, and press Edit. Provide a new name and press the button 'Clone Device'.
2. Now, create the new virtual device using this cloned configuration.
3. The new device does not raise any longer the invalid configuration error messages.

Comment: My virtual devices starts but then crashes after startup.

Comment: Wow, what a crazy bug.

Answer (score 4):

the answer by @coderazzi is correct, but those who are new to intellij and are facing problems in finding appropriate settings here's some images

1. Open AVD Settings[image]
2. Open Device Definitions and select any device definitions eg. Nexus S [image]
3. Click on Clone and then add a new name[image]
4. Create a new AVD using the new definitions "**Bug Free Nexus S**". Now use this as your target emulator and you will face no problems.[image]